# Temperature equalization by radiation between two coaxial cylinders - independent of diameters?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, radiation

Ignoring end effects, assume I have a cylinder of diameter d0 at controlled temperature k0 and then introduce a smaller diameter cylinder of diameter d1 and temperature k1 to the interior.

Does the time for the small cylinder temperature to reach k0 have any dependencies on the diameters d0 or d1? [assuming constant mass]

Comment: Well yes because the total power received by the smaller cylinder will be proportional to its area ($\propto d_1^2$). Normally its mass and therfore specific heat would be proportional to $d_1^3$ so the smaller the cylinder the faster it heats up. Though you seem to be imposing the restriction that mass/total heat capacity of the smaller cylinder doesn't change, which seems counterintuitive.

Comment: @JohnRennie The real device is that the inner cylinder is fixed diameter and mass and the outer one is temperature controlled (so mass irrelevant) but its diameter can vary.